# Printing value of button's data attribute in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table that gets printed with a HTML button on each row.  PHP is used to give each button a possibly different value in a data attribute that I have defined.

Once the whole table has been printed, I want to use some JQuery to print out a button's data attribute value when the user clicks.

Each button looks like this:

```
<button rel="test" data-myatt="hello world" id="myid">Click Me</button>
```

The JQuery I have so far is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#my_table').on('tr button[rel=test]').click(function() {
   alert($('#myid').data('myatt'));           
   });
 });
```

But when the buttons are clicked, I just get 'undefined' returned.

**EDIT:** The undefined error has gone (thanks to @Shion) but now the value of the data attribute in the first row is printed regardless of which button is pressed.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This has probably to do with your ID.

On a normal HTML-Page any ID should just be defined once.
If all of your buttons share the same ID, there might be some problems. Like the one you mentioned.

Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my_table').on('tr button[rel=test]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).find('button').data('myatt'));           
    });
});
```

Comment: That has stopped the 'undefined' message but now only the data attribute value of the first button in the table is printed regardless of the button that is pressed.  +1 for getting rid of the undefined message though.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<button rel="test" data_myatt="hello world" id="myid">Click Me</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#my_table').on('tr button[rel=test]').click(function() {
     alert($('#myid').attr('data_myatt'));           
   });
 });
```

Comment: Agreed - the jQuery `data` function doesn't store and retrieve data using attributes. Use `attr`.

Comment: jQuery does store the data as `.data()` but only if you define the `data-myattr` before document ready. This is since jQuery 1.6. [see this link](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

It just came to my mind. Why are you using the On-method of jQuery at all?

This Fiddle works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/esVnV/

Are the requirements something different?

As I saw just now: Are you sure you are using the On-Method correctly? Refer to the jQuery-Docs for more help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this will be causing your problem but it looks as if your buttons all have the same ids -

```
<button rel="test" data-myatt="hello world" id="myid">Click Me</button>
```

Ids should be unique within a HTML document. If you can, generate unique ids for your buttons via php.